How to use putty private key in linux
I generated a public/private key pair using puttygen in Ubuntu. I sent the public key to the sever manager who have added it in the system. My question is how should I use my private key to connect to the server in my local machine? Any comments and suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks,
D.
